# 他者から受け取ったRコードの文字化けなど

Tags: r

よろしくお願いいたします。

タイトル通りですが、書籍についていたRのコードをHPからダウンロードし、自分のRstudioで再生したところ、文字化けが多くて困りました．とくに、日本語はほとんど文字化け状態です．
そういったこともあってか、コードを走らせようとしてもエラーばかりでちょっと困っています．

このような問題を解決できる手段を御存じではないでしょうか．

Comment: ダウンロード元のURLを追記していただけませんか。

Answer (score 1):

RStudio のメニューから `File > Reopen with Encoding...` を選択するとエンコーディングを変更してファイルを開きなおすことができます．
日本語なら，

- CP932
- SHIFT-JIS
- UTF-8
- ISO2022-JP

のどれかだと思います．

文字化けした状態で 編集・保存 してしまっていると，正しいエンコーディングで開きなおしても文字化けは直らないかもしれません．
その場合はもう一度スクリプトをダウンロードしなおして 試してみてください．

Answer (score 1):

Windows環境からくる文字化けするファイル、困りますよね。

「文字コードがUTF8でない」事が文字化けの原因です。
自分のところでは、外部から来たファイルは必ず最初にutf8にしてから、
共有するようにしています。

以下はMac/Linuxでのコードサンプルです

```
for f in `ls *.csv`
do
    iconv -f cp932 -t utf-8 < $f > utf8-$f
done
```

2019/10 追記です。上記はシェルによっても動作が変わってしまうので、
どの文字コードも正しく日本のUTF-8に変換してくれる素晴らしいコマンド、nkf を使うのが良いと思います。

```
sudo apt install nkf
find ./ -name '*.tsv' -print0 | xargs -0 nkf -Lu -w --overwrite
```

Comment: このシェルスクリプトには問題があります。たとえばファイル名に半角スペースが含まれていると誤動作します。`find` コマンドの `-exec` オプションを使うなど、他の方法にすると互換性が高くなります。

Comment: そうですね。またiconvだとコード指定をファイルごとに指定しないといけない問題もありますので、最近は自動で文字コードも判別してくれる nkf コマンドを使ったワンライナーで処理する事が多いです：このようにしています  `find ./ -name '*.tsv' -print0 | xargs -0 nkf -Lu -w --overwrite`  必ず入力時に全てUTF-8にして、sjis混入事故が起こらないように意識しています。 Rでしたらglue パッケージと組み合わせて `system(glue("find {sjis2utf8_dir} -name '*.tsv' -print0 | xargs -0 nkf -Lu -w --overwrite"))` の一行で処理できます